# display images using uicollectionview with zoom enable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I want to display some images using collection view. What I use scrollview inside cell and image view in scroll view. image are  zoom in and zoom out. when cell is reuse new cell scroll view and image view size are same as old which was zoomed.
want when cell reuse scroll view size got default. 
how to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

@hello you have to Set gesture in Imageview & usung below methods ,
you can easily set Zoom in & Zoom Out Using Gesture

in ViewDID..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

 scrollViewMain.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
    scrollViewMain.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    scrollViewMain.clipsToBounds = NO;
    scrollViewMain.delegate = self;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapTwice = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapTwice:)];
    // set number of taps required
    tapTwice.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;

    // now add the gesture recogniser to a view
    // this will be the view that recognises the gesture
    [scrollViewMain addGestureRecognizer:tapTwice];
}
//------For Zoom IN ScrollView-------------------------------------------------------
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)inScroll {
    //self.iPickedPicture.center = ivPicture.center;
    return _imgView;
}


- (void)tapOnce:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {
        //on a single  tap, call zoomToRect in UIScrollView
        if ([scrollViewMain zoomScale] > 1.0)
        {
        float newScale = 1.0;
        CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomToCenter:newScale withCenter:[gesture locationInView:scrollViewMain]];
        [scrollViewMain zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            float newScale =  3.5;
            CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomToCenter:newScale withCenter:[gesture locationInView:scrollViewMain]];
            [scrollViewMain zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];

        }
    }
    - (void)tapTwice:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
    {
        //on a double tap, call zoomToRect in UIScrollView
        if ([scrollViewMain zoomScale] == 1.0) {

        float newScale = [scrollViewMain zoomScale] * 3.5;
        CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomToCenter:newScale withCenter:[gesture locationInView:scrollViewMain]];
        [scrollViewMain zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
        }else
        {
            float newScale = 1.0;
            CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomToCenter:newScale withCenter:[gesture locationInView:scrollViewMain]];
            [scrollViewMain zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
        }

    }

    - (CGRect)zoomToCenter:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

        CGRect zoomRect;
        zoomRect.size.height = scrollViewMain.frame.size.height / scale;
        zoomRect.size.width  = scrollViewMain.frame.size.width  / scale;

        zoomRect.origin.x = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
        zoomRect.origin.y = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

        return zoomRect;


    }
```